# Changing javascript array name,value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays

Simple javascript question:

I have an array (50=50; 49=49; 143=143; 4005=4005; ... )
which i want to turn into (50; 49; 143; 4005; ...).

The name will always be the same as the value, in the name=value pair.
It will always be a number (but of various lengths).

I just cant get my head around it using .split

Thanks

Comment: Could you please be more precise? Arrays of the form `(50=50; 49=49; 143=143; 4005=4005; ... )` don't exist in JavaScript. We cannot help you if we don't know what you actually have.

Comment: Do you mean to say you have a _string_ of those values from which you want to make an array?

Comment: no point in defining useless array having all keys same as value

Comment: You should clarify that in your question and provide a syntactically valid example. Otherwise it is not of much use to other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean you have an array like this:

```
var arr = ['50=50;','49=49;','143=143;','4005=4005;'];
```

Then, you may employ `split` like this:

```
var newArr = [], ii;
for (ii = 0; ii < arr.length; ii += 1) {
    newArr.push(parseInt(arr[ii].split('=')[0], 10));
}
```

This will result in `newArr` being equal to this:

```
var newArr = [50, 49, 143, 4005];
```

The way `split` works is it divides a string up into an array based on a delimiter string. In this example, we've used `'='` as the delimiter, so we end up with arrays like this:

```
['50', '50;']
['49', '49;']
// etc.
```

Then, index into the first element and pass it to `parseInt` to produce a number, and `push` onto a new array with just number elements.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/d87W7/).

#### Addendum

If you aren't starting with an actual JavaScript array, but a string that you'd like to turn into an array, then add this step before the previous ones to get yourself the original array:

```
var str = '(50=50; 49=49; 143=143; 4005=4005;)';
var arr = str.replace(/\(|\)|;/g, '').split(' ');
```

Comment: great. exactly what i needed. just one question, what is the value 10 doing in your solution? thanks

Comment: When using `parseInt`, one should always specify the second parameter, which is the radix/base of the number you're parsing. That's why there's a `10`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt